# Is it possible to require one of many props for Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a Vue component that must either take in a piece of text or a link. When there is a link that is passed in I want to create an anchor tag and when there is a piece of text inputted I want to create a span. My current problem that it looks like each Vue prop gets its own validator, i.e.

```
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    text: {
      type: String
    }
```

The above code does not fulfill my needs because it will require url, which is something that I want to be optional if text is passed.

How would I make it so that this component took in either a url or a piece of text by requirement?

Bonus: how would I make it so that the component could only take one? i.e. fail if both URL and text are passed in.

Comment: Would using a single prop with a validator fit your needs ?

Comment: You may use `computed` to validate as you like.

Comment: that is interesting, would you recommend using a computed value based on the format of the text, kind of like using a regex to determine if the text passed in is a link?

Comment: I support what @Simon said. The way you are thinking is extremely hard, may be sometime unnecessery.

Comment: @Turna why not simply use a prop validator ? Since there will only be url *or* text, I would use a single `value` prop, then add (if needed) a computed value which would return the type, depending on how it is supposed to be used. I could make a better solution if I knew what would be the difference in use between the url or the text

Comment: @Seblor Yes! I would do that too. But I think Simon wants two prop names. (I guess)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed prop validators must be pure functions since they do not have access to THIS of the component. But you may solve your issue by using a single prop of type Object:

```js
props:
{
  params:
  {
    type: Object,
    validator: (value) =>
    {
      return !!value && 
        Object.keys(value).length === 1 && 
        ['url', 'text'].includes(Object.keys) && 
        typeof Object.values(value)[0] === 'string' &&
        Object.values(value)[0] !== '';
    }
  }
}
```